# Why the randomize function for absolute margin is not working?

Tags: javascript, function, random

I have a HTML and I'm trying to randomize each layer top margin attribute.

```js
function randomize() {
  let r;
  let list = document.querySelectorAll("span");
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
    list.forEach((list) => {
      style.top = `${r} + px`;
    });
  }
}
```

```css
span {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  z-index: -2;
}
```

```html
<div class="parallax">
  <span class="layer" data-speed="-5">10110</span>
  <span class="layer" data-speed="-5">0</span>
</div>
```

What am I getting wrong here? I can't find the proper solution.

Comment: Are there any errors in your console? What is `style`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

1. To use the `top` CSS property, the element needs to have a position defined. You can set that in the CSS (`position: relative`) or set it in the JS. *(**EDIT** OP added CSS that they had already which set the `position`. Leaving this here for people that use `top` without setting an element's `position`)*
2. You need to move the randomization into the `forEach` otherwise it will have the same value for all `span` elements
3. You need to attach the `style` prop to the element you are passing in the `forEach`, e.g., `list.style.styleProp`

```js
function randomize() {
  let r;
  let list = document.querySelectorAll("span");
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    list.forEach((list) => {
      r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
      list.style.top = r + 'px';
    });
  }
}

randomize();
```

```css
span {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  z-index: -2;
}
```

```html
<div class="parallax">
  <span class="layer" data-speed="-5">10110</span>
  <span class="layer" data-speed="-5">0</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I had some CSS styling but I forgot to mention in the post, I already edited the snippet. Thank you for your answer, it worked like a charm here.

Comment: @guilhermxlopes cool! I updated my answer with your CSS and removed the `position` in the JS.

Answer (score 0):

Because `<span>` is natively an inline element, and margin has no effect.

Change your `<span>`s to `<div>`s.